# Angular 4 - argument of type string[] is not assignable to type parameter of type 'string'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following function that shows the following error in the TSlinting - Can anyone suggest why I am getting this error?

`Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to type parameter of type 'string'`

```
cancelEvent(id): any {
    let pages: Array<string> = [];
    let requestParams = new HttpParams().set('pages[]', pages);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set String[] in headers, it should be of type string,

The definition of the set method is:

```
set(param: string, value: string): HttpParams;
```

so value can be only a **`string`**.

```
let requestParams = new HttpParams().set('pages[]', pages); // it should be string
```

Answer (score 1):

HttpParams().set can set only string values.However you can do something like below

```
   let pages: Array<string> = [];
    let requestParams = new HttpParams().set('pages[]', pages.join(','));
```

and use split() to get values back into array.